# Variadic functions problems

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, variadic-functions

Let's consider such code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#ifdef debug
#undef debug
#endif

#define debug(format, ...) tpk(format, __VA_ARGS__)

void tpk(const char* format, ...)
{
  const unsigned int len = 1024;
  char buffer[len];
  va_list args;

  va_start(args, format);
  vsprintf(buffer, format, args);
  va_end(args);

  printf(buffer);
}


int main()
{
  debug("No, you don't! ",  "But I do! %d %s\n", 34, "blabla");
  return 0;
}
```

Things to consider:

I have some code to debug, that's why I have to undef the debug (please don't ask me why, because the way the headers are included in project is kind of messed up).

Don't worry about buffer overflows and such, this is only for debugging purposes.

What's not working:

I only get the `No, you don't!` message and that's all. However, if I remove the first argument from `debug` the message is printed nicely. What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE: I made a stupid mistake. I give a format string, that has no formatting parametres, hence everything works as it should. The solution for this, would be to modify the function:

```
#define debug(str, format, ...) tpk(str, format, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Print the str and after that use variadic functions on format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're saying is no different from:

```
printf("No, you don't! ",  "But I do! %d %s\n", 34, "blabla");
```

Can you see what that does?

Hint: What's the format string?

Comment: With an exceptions that such printf will generate compilation error [:

Oh God... Not I see the error.

Answer (score 2):

In the first call to `debug` function:

```
debug("No, you don't! ",  "But I do! %d %s\n", 34, "blabla");
```

the first argument is the `format` argument for `vsprintf` which will parse it and try to find what to substitute. As `"No, you don't!"` contain nothing to substitute, the remaining parameters are ignored.

If you delete that part, `"But I do! %d %s\n"` contains `%d` and `%s` that will be replaced.